# Image displaying incorrectly in Tkinter, is machine the problem?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, google-chrome-os

As the title says, I'm working in Tkinter with an incredibly simple test program.

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drn0k.png)

I'm running Python 3.7.3 on an HP Chromebook. Everything is up to date, as far as I know, but I could be wrong.

When I run the program, the window appears on my screen, and my guess is that it ATTEMPTS to display the image. However, this is what happens:

[One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFst6.png) [Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlTS6.png) [Three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS87L.png) [Four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z755.png)

And as of this posting, only ONCE did the image appear perfectly:

[Intended Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BMHd.png)

Does anybody have any idea what's happening and would you be able to provide me with some guidance?

Do you think this is a software issue, or hardware? Sometimes I feel that the fact I started coding on a Chromebook is the cause of some strange problems I've been having, such as this and something else related to Pygame. Maybe I'm biased, but I feel that my machine isn't compatible with the stuff I'm trying to work with, and I might be better off looking into something new. Well, just an idea anyway.

Comment: Your last line in tkinter should be `window.mainloop()` . Do you have updated version of Pillow? Do you have PIL and Pillow installed (it should be only Pillow)?

Comment: I've already added the `window.mainloop()` part, and no dice. Yes, Pillow is updated. And yes, I only have Pillow installed.

Comment: Have not been able to reproduce this issue with Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I'm really starting to lean to the side of this being some kind of incompatibility between my machine and the software. I've been Googling and posting to different sources for the past few days and haven't seen anyone else experiencing a problem like this. C'est la vie, I suppose.

Comment: try getting rid of `label.image = photo` ?